# VBA to show/hide rows based on whether a cell's value is zero

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I have an Excel sheet where I would like to hide or unhide certain rows depending on the value in another cell.

In Short:
The whole thing should depend on the value in cell `C2`, `D2`, `E2`.

If `C2` is **blank** I would like `rows 31 to 40` be hidden, if it is **not blank**, they need to be **visible**.

The same for the other three cells, always hiding/unhiding the following 10 rows:

```
D2 --> rows 41 to 50
E2 --> rows 51 to 60
```

I tried this code but it is not working and I do not get any error either:

```
Sub Hide_rows()
    If Range("LS!C2") = 0 Then
        Rows("31:40").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        If Range("LS!D2") = 0 Then
            Rows("41:50").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            If Range("LS!E2") = 0 Then
                Rows("51:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                If Range("LS!C2") > 0 Then
                    Rows("31:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    If Range("LS!D2") > 0 Then
                        Rows("41:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Else
                        If Range("LS!E2") > 0 Then
                            Rows("51:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Else

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: How is it "not working"?  That's very vague and not enough information to goive much help. A good first step  is to **step through the code** (with F8) one line at a time, checking the values of variables etc as you go, to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: I would suggest you use `ElseIf` statement for readability.

Comment: I would suggest never ever using `ElseIf`, however I am going to edit your post (again) to format your code better for clarity,

Comment: Proper formatting including indentation is important for many reason, and this is a good example of why.  Run the procedure with F8 and it should be easier to find where the problem lies. Also a **highly recommended** read is: [Chip Pearson's **Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).  Also, check out the [tour] (it's earns you a badge!) as well as "[ask]" and also read about including a [mcve].   (Welcome, by the way!)

Comment: @ashleedawg I could see some reasons  sometimes, but if you can point me on some for the "never ever", I would appreciate.

Comment: @VincentG Obviously, at the end of the day, everything in coding is a matter of personal preference, but I think it's generally accepted that avoiding `ElseIf` is better for the same reason you suggested *to* use it: clarity in making code easier to read.  IMHO there's always an simpler way to layout a set of conditions instead of relying on several nested `IF`'s, or to using `ELSEIF` at all. No offence was intended; the right way to do it is "whatever way makes the code work"  :-)  (I have the same aversion to using `EXIT` or `GOTO` statements after years of getting my fingers smacked.

Comment: VincentG - case in point : @Jeeped's answer below.  Rethinking the answer from the top provides a much cleaner solution compared to "nested anything's"

Comment: @ashleedawg  IMHO advise to "never" do something is rarely if ever good advise.  Can you offer any justification in this case?

Comment: @ashleedawg No offense taken

Comment: @chrisneilsen - IMHO, "never" is an appropriate instruction when teaching someone "new" (to coding, or anything else in life) about best practices.  In reality, any rule has an exception, but it's best when, right off the bat, the person gets used to finding alternate solutions instead of getting used to lazy or inefficient methods. Other examples where I say that: "Never use `GOTO`", "Never use `On Error Resume Next`", "Always use `Option Explicit`". I break all those rules occasionally (depending on many factors) but they are good rules-of-thumb nonetheless. "Never" gets a point across.

Comment: @ashleedwg, hmmm so by never you don't really mean never?  Perhaps you mean don't do it unless you have a really good reason to do it and fully understand the consequences?   Under this definition I'm 100% for the other items you commented.   Still, I'm curious why you lump `ElseIf` into the same catagory

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like you just need the following lines:

```
With Sheets("LS")
        .Rows("31:40").EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range("C2") = 0)
        .Rows("41:50").EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range("D2") = 0)
        .Rows("51:60").EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range("E2") = 0)
End With
```

**EDIT** as per Chris's point - the following will suffice:

```
With Sheets("LS")
        .Rows("31:40").Hidden = (.Range("C2") = 0)
        .Rows("41:50").Hidden = (.Range("D2") = 0)
        .Rows("51:60").Hidden = (.Range("E2") = 0)
End With
```

Comment: Minor quibble: `EntireRow` is redundant since you are already specifying whole rows

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to this an will take into account all the hints you gave also about how to formate and present a question.
However, this code works perfectly fine for me and I am very happy to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Put this Worksheet_Change event driven sub procedure in the LS worksheet's private code sheet (right-clcik name tab, View Code), not in a public module code sheet.

```
sub worksheet_change(byval Target as range)
    if not intersect(target, range("C2:E2")) is nothing then
        on error goto safe_exit
        application.enableevents = false
        rows("31:40").entirerow.hidden = isempty(cells(2, "C"))
        rows("41:50").entirerow.hidden = isempty(cells(2, "D"))
        rows("51:60").entirerow.hidden = isempty(cells(2, "E"))
    end if
safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true
end sub
```

Any change made to C2:E2 will trigger this sub procdure and the hidden/unhidden nature of those rows will be re-evaluated.

Comment: [Lateral Thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_thinking)  :-)